# How to increment primary key not set to identity in merge statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a case that I want to do `MERGE` statement on a table with a primary key not set to identity and I want to increment the primary key column value within the `INSERT` part of the `MERGE` statement.

Comment: Show us what you have at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- declare `int` variable to grab the max Id
- declare SQL variable to create sequence dynamically to make start with the max Id determined before
- now alter your table to make the primary key column has default constraint that get the next value of the created sequence
- do you merge statement
- clean up the sequence and the default constraint

Code sample:

```
DECLARE @id INT;
    SELECT @id = MAX(Id) + 1
    FROM dbo.Table;
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempSeqTable') IS NOT NULL
        DROP SEQUENCE [dbo].[tempSeqTable];

    SET @sql
        = N'CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[tempSeqTable] AS INT START WITH ' + CAST(@id AS NVARCHAR)
          + N'INCREMENT BY 1';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Table
    ADD CONSTRAINT Id_Default  DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR tempSeqTable FOR Id;
-- do the merge statement.

ALTER TABLE dbo.Tabel DROP CONSTRAINT Id_Default;
DROP SEQUENCE [dbo].[tempSeqTable];
```

Comment: The code as written will only work in single user, single session environment.

Comment: @Alex yes this for script that runs once for maintenance or support case.